# Проблема с поиском повторяющихся символов

Tags: python, строки, list

Программа задумана искать повторяющиеся символы с шагом 3. И я не понимаю почему не выводится.

```
s = input()
ch = []
m=[]
ch.append(s)
if s == s[::-1]:
    print("YES")
else:
    for i in s:
        if ch.count(i)>1:
            c = s.find(i)
            lent = len(s)
            if c%3==0:
                k = s.find(i,c)
                if (k - c)%4 ==0:
                    m.append(i)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    print(m)
```

Вход: sinus
Желаемый результат:['s', 's']
Выводит: []

Comment: Приведите пример входящих данных, данных, которые вы получаете и желаемы результат(и почему именно его). Для редактирования вопроса, нажмите кнопку "Править" под вопросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В условии `if ch.count(i)>1:` идет проверка сколько элементов 's' в списке ch, а в списке ch один элемент 'sinus', а элементов 's' нет ни одного. Все цикл заканчивается. Результат [].